# How to fix InvalidOperationException in UnityEngine.EventSystems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a movement system in my Unity3d game, but when first mixing input systems over different functions (at the time old input system for movement), the second time i opened up the project i got these messages shown below. I then tried to fix it at first by using only new input system, but the issue stayed (i thought this would fix it because it looked like the error report was very long at first, and i didn't have the energy to read it all).

the error reports are:

```
InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling to Input System package in Player Settings.
UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInput.GetButtonDown (System.String buttonName) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/BaseInput.cs:126)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ShouldActivateModule () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:227)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:474)
```

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB3Uo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJj6P.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdkr6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJiSa.png)

Yeah this "what did you try" stuff doesn't really apply much here, but i have to write something, but i did expect unity to have figured it self out.

Answer (score 0):

Set "Active Input Handling" to "Both" in the Player Settings.

From the Docs [found here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Installation.html):

> You can find the corresponding setting in the Player settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Player), under Active Input Handling. You can change this setting at any time. Doing so will restart the Editor.
>
> > Note: You can enable both the old and the new system at the same time. To do so, set Active Input Handling to Both.